# Jmeter - Run .jmx file through command line and get the summary report in a html, csv as well as XML output - All three

Tags: jmeter

Currently, I am giving below on the command line. When I add CSV, it doesn't give output in csv format. Can you please provide complete command for all three outputs.

Sample 1:

!JMeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -n -t ProgramServices.jmx -l JmeterReports\TestReport.xml -j JmeterReports\jmeter.log

Sample 2:
JMeter -n -t Creation_SLW.jmx -l JmeterReports/TestReport.csv  -e -o JmeterReports/htmlReport/ -j JmeterReports/jmeter.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview) documentation

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples **from CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.

So as of latest [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) you can only generate the HTML dashboard from .jtl file which is in CSV format and the contents of the file has to be inline with the [Result File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

I would recommend reverting your changes and going for CSV + HTML Reporting Dashboard with the default configuration (or with your necessary amendments)

If you need XML with the full data as well - you can add i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to your test plan and specify the desired file name and the metrics which you want to store:

[image]

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T. I could use this workaround